# General purpose GPS tracker app for Android that takes stops into account

Tags: android, gps-tracking

I'm looking for an Android application that

- tracks GPS signal (like many other sports trackers), and
- apart from usual statistics, like max. speed, average speed, covered distance and time, also displays time spent moving/stationary, and
- calculates average moving speed from that.

Most apps I've found don't care if you move or not, just calculate an average speed for the whole route.